Resolving 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error when integrating Tailwind CSS with npm and yarn
When I attempted to integrate Tailwind CSS into my project using the command "npx tailwindcss init", I encountered the following error:

npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND npm ERR! Cannot find module
'./yarn-lock.js'.

How can this issue be resolved?
I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling both "npm" and "yarn", and currently have the latest versions of both installed. However, they do not appear to be compatible with Tailwind CSS.

try this one
npm cache clean --force


Thank you for your answer. However, the problem was in the package management system. I reinstalled Nodejs.
